# Putting a percentage to put in a form control

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've got an access database which we use to book web advertising against a forecast/inventory limit.

I have three unbound text boxes which work out three things from the continuous form it sits below:

Impressions[txtImpressions]: `=IIf(IsNull(Sum([Impressions]))=True,0,Sum([Impressions]))`

Forecast[txtForecast]: `(Populated on form load by vba)`

Remaining Availability[txtDifference]: `=[txtForecast]-[txtImpressions]`

I would like one more box, which shows the impressions as a percentage of the forecast, so if txtImpressions contains 200 and txtForecast contains 400, I'd like the percentage box to show '50%'

I've tried =[txtForecast]/[txtImpressions] to at least divide it, but it always give me a value of 1. I've tried

```
=Format([txtForecast]/[txtImpressions]), Percent))
```

but that doesn't help either.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Format property of textbox with percentage to `Percent` (in Form designer)

You see always "1" if `Decimal Places` of your text box is set to 0.

`Comtrol Source` property of this text box should be `=[txtForecast]/[txtImpressions]`

Comment: Thank you, I was totally forgetting about the format of the textbox.